# REST API for getting cart details of specific customer

Tags: cart, customer, api, rest-api, magento-2.0

I am trying to get the allocated cart detail for specific customer, but there are no api available to getting the cart information from customer detail (from customerId).
How can i get the cart information for particular customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **customer** API, then just use `GET /V1/carts/mine`

If using **admin** APIs, the flow should be like this:

1. `POST /V1/customers/:customerId/carts`, will crete cart for specified customer and return cart ID
2. Later you can use that cart ID in `GET /V1/carts/:cartId`

If cart already exists and need to be accessed by the **admin**, it should be possible to form search criteria with filter by customer ID and pass it to `GET /V1/carts`

Comment: I am trying to search but getting error response, here is my search request http://MYHOST/rest/default/V1/carts/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value]=5&searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][conditionType]=eq

Comment: Please provide more details, what error are you getting?

Comment: @ArunKasyakar Does it work for you or help needed?

Comment: @AlexPaliarush is it possible if customer login add cart items to customer cart, if possible please explain, Using REST API. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/199748/55981

Comment: Thanks @AlexPaliarush, I was stuck in placing the order as a customer using Magento 2 API. The order was placing fine but the customer name was showing Guest always. Your answer helped me to dig in the right direction.